# How to optimize if-statemnts php?

Tags: php, if-statement, optimization

How to optimize PHP??
I'd like to optimize this code with if-statements in PHP.

```
$head =  make_number($_GET['id']);
if(isset($head)){
    echo $head;
}
else {
    $head =  make_number($_GET['id']);
    if(isset($head)){
        echo $head;
    }
    else {
        $head =  make_number($_GET['url']);
        if(isset($head)){
            echo $head;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's php, not javascript... as for optimization, why make_number TWICE on `id`? "Hmm, chopped off my hand, and it didn't work. I'll just chop again".

Comment: Also, is this code running slow? Do you have any evidence that this is actually causing a bottleneck. Unless you know what's slowing down your code, optimization is usually inefficient

Answer (score 2):

You can use null coalescing operator from new PHP features:

```
$head = make_number($_GET['id']) ?? 
        make_number($_GET['url']) ?? 
        make_number($_GET['xyz']);
```

Or if you can't use php 7 features - use short-circuit OR's:

```
$head = make_number($_GET['id']) or 
$head = make_number($_GET['url']) or 
$head = make_number($_GET['xyz']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$head1 = make_number($_GET['id']);
$head2 = make_number($_GET['url']);

if(isset($head1) && isset($head2)){
    echo $head;
}
```

Comment: I add 100 $head is overload .
i need 1 result ==> request 100 $head ==> overload .

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
$headID = make_number($_GET['id']);
$headURL = make_number($_GET['url']);

if(isset($headID))
    echo $headID;
else {
    if(isset($headURL))
        echo $headURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      echo make_number($_GET['id']);
 }
elseif(isset($_GET['url'])){
      echo make_number($_GET['url']);
 }
 // if none of them is set
else{

      echo 'Nothing to echo';
}
```

Hope it helps